# Casting with Dynamic Generics

Tags: wpf, generics, dynamic, casting

I did try to read the many SO questions about this subject of .Net generics & dynamic casting, but still can't see how to apply it to my WPF app.

I have one View and ViewModel with which I maintain data for several tables.  The tables all have the same column / field names that show up in the view, ie. description, createdate, etc.  I am using one common View and ViewModel for the tables because I can more easily maintain and reuse the code if it is all in one ViewModel file.

When I navigate to the View, I know which table to load and use.  What I need to be able to do is select records into a strongly-typed IEnumerable, like this:

```
private IEnumerable<Foo> _itemsList;  
switch (_tableName)
{
    case Foo:
    {
        _itemsList = (from myrow in UoW.FooRepository.Get()
            orderby myrow.descr
            select new FooModel()
            {
                foo_id = myrow.foo_id,
                descr = myrow.descr,
                createdate = myrow.createdate,                   
            }).ToList();
        break;
    }
}
```

From what I read, I need to first do something like this:

```
switch (_tableName)
{
   case Foo:
   {
       var mylist = typeof(List<>);
       Type[] typeArgs = { typeof(Foo) };
       var makegenlist = ls.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
       object o = Activator.CreateInstance(makegenlist);
       break;
    }
}
```

But what is the next step after creating the object 'o' with the Activator?  How do I then create the strongly-typed IEnumerable for the select?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already constructing a concrete generic type (aka a "closed" one). So, given the assumptions that you have by then already made by doing so, this simple downcast to conclude your logic should work:

```
(IEnumerable<Foo>)o
```

(because of course, you also know that List<> implements IList<>, IEnumerable<>, etc)

(Your question gave me the feeling that you may be trying to solve the XY problem, though.)

'HTH,

Comment: Yes, that works after I changed my ViewModel declaration of _itemsList to a dynamic type instead of IEnumerable<Foo>..  Thank you.